# TcpClient and TcpServer that automatically connect when server available

Tags: c#

I am creating a TcpServer and TcpClient that the client will connect the server automatically once the server available (keep trying). And I don't want to lose data which means that when client sending data to server and suddenly server down, it will retry again so the below MnitorMiniTcpClientOwn.SendData will keep trying until sucessful.

However there is problem in production that happens randomly where the server will receive multiple same command because of the keep trying loop in SendData request. I am not good in network programming can anyone spot defect in the code?

Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace NewCMS.Repositories
{
    public class MonitorMiniTcpClientOwn : IDisposable
    {
        public string ServerIP = "127.0.0.1";
        public int Port = 9090;
        TcpClient tc = null;
        string dataFromClient = string.Empty;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        Thread RunningThread = null;
        public bool IsRunning = false;
        public string _Name = string.Empty;

        public virtual string InitialText
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Start(string name)
        {
            _Name = name;
            if (tc != null)
            {
                Stop();
            }

            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(StartThread);
            RunningThread = new Thread(ts);
            RunningThread.Start();
        }

        public void StopWithoutAbort()
        {
            if (tc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    tc.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            if (stream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                IsRunning = false;
                StopWithoutAbort();
                if (RunningThread != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RunningThread.Abort();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        protected void StartThread()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    tc = new TcpClient();
                    tc.Connect(ServerIP, Port);

                    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];

                    stream = tc.GetStream();
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = stream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        dataFromClient += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, read);

                        string[] strs = dataFromClient.Split('\n');
                        if (strs != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length - 1; i++)
                            {
                                ProcessCommand(tc, strs[i]);
                            }
                            if (dataFromClient.EndsWith("\n"))
                            {
                                ProcessCommand(tc, strs[strs.Length - 1]);
                                dataFromClient = string.Empty;
                            }
                            else
                                dataFromClient = strs[strs.Length - 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StopWithoutAbort();
                    if (IsRunning == false)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    IsRunning = true;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void ProcessCommand(TcpClient tc, string str)
        {
        }

        public Exception SendData(string text)
        {
            Exception result = null;
            int tryIndex = 0;
            int tryCount = 5;
            while (tryIndex < tryCount)
            {
                tryIndex++;
                try
                {
                    byte[] bufText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
                    stream.Write(bufText, 0, bufText.Length);
                    result = null;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex;
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            return result;
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace NewCMS.Repositories
{
    public class MonitorMiniStoreTcpServerOwn : IDisposable
    {
        public int Port = 9090;
        public TcpListener tl = null;
        public Thread RunningThread = null;
        public List<Thread> RunningAcceptTcp = new List<Thread>();
        public List<MyTcpServerParam> AllConnections = new List<MyTcpServerParam>();
        public bool IsRunning = false;
        public string _Name = string.Empty;

        public virtual void Start(string name)
        {
            _Name = name;
            if (RunningThread != null)
            {
                Stop();
            }

            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(StartThread);
            RunningThread = new Thread(ts);
            RunningThread.Start();
        }

        public virtual void StopWithoutAbort()
        {
            if (tl != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    tl.Stop();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            if (AllConnections != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int i = AllConnections.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (AllConnections[i].Stream != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                AllConnections[i].Stream.Close();
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                    }
                    AllConnections.Clear();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            if (RunningAcceptTcp != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int i = RunningAcceptTcp.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            RunningAcceptTcp[i].Abort();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    RunningAcceptTcp.Clear();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        public virtual void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                IsRunning = false;
                if (tl != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tl.Stop();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }

                if (AllConnections != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = AllConnections.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            if (AllConnections[i].Stream != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    AllConnections[i].Stream.Close();
                                }
                                catch { }
                            }
                        }
                        AllConnections.Clear();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                if (RunningAcceptTcp != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = RunningAcceptTcp.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                RunningAcceptTcp[i].Abort();
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                        RunningAcceptTcp.Clear();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                if (RunningThread != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RunningThread.Abort();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        protected void StartThread()
        {
            int retry = 0;
            IsRunning = true;
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    tl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
                    tl.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
                    tl.Start();
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    retry++;
                }
            }
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient clientSocket = tl.AcceptTcpClient();
                    MyTcpServerParam p = new MyTcpServerParam();
                    p.Client = clientSocket;

                    ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(AcceptSocket);
                    Thread t = new Thread(pts);
                    //lock (RunningAcceptTcpSync)
                    {
                        RunningAcceptTcp.Add(t);
                    }
                    t.Start(p);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StopWithoutAbort();
                    if (IsRunning)
                    {
                        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(StartThread);
                        RunningThread = new Thread(ts);
                        RunningThread.Start();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void AcceptSocket(object obb)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsRunning == false) return;
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                string dataFromClient = string.Empty;

                MyTcpServerParam para = (MyTcpServerParam)obb;
                NetworkStream networkStream = para.Client.GetStream();
                para.Stream = networkStream;
                //lock (AllConnectionsSync)
                {
                    AllConnections.Add(para);
                }

                int read = 0;
                while ((read = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dataFromClient += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom, 0, read);

                        string[] strs = dataFromClient.Split('\n');
                        if (strs != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length - 1; i++)
                            {
                                ProcessCommand(para, strs[i]);
                            }
                            if (dataFromClient.EndsWith("\n"))
                            {
                                ProcessCommand(para, strs[strs.Length - 1]);
                                dataFromClient = string.Empty;
                            }
                            else
                                dataFromClient = strs[strs.Length - 1];
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    //lock (RunningAcceptTcpSync)
                    {
                        RunningAcceptTcp.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
                try
                {
                    MyTcpServerParam para = (MyTcpServerParam)obb;
                    //lock (AllConnectionsSync)
                    {
                        AllConnections.Remove(para);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        public virtual void ProcessCommand(MyTcpServerParam param, string str)
        {
        }

        public Exception SendData(MyTcpServerParam param, string text)
        {
            Exception result = null;
            int tryIndex = 0;
            int tryCount = 5;
            while (tryIndex < tryCount)
            {
                try
                {
                    tryIndex++;
                    byte[] bufText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
                    param.Stream.Write(bufText, 0, bufText.Length);
                    result = null;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //lock (AllConnectionsSync)
                    {
                        AllConnections.Remove(param);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
                return result;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug the code as well as when debugging try to simulate the Server not being available..?

Comment: yes i have tried when the server is unavailable the client throws exception and being caught, then when the server is up, the client connect successfully however it does not show any sign of sending multiple command to server. The random problems only happen in production server that difficult to track.

Comment: perhaps it's in the Threading have you thought about throwing in some logic on the Server side and tracking perhaps a Message ID and seeing if that Message is already in the queue..? it's hard to render any advice and or help if one can't reproduce what it is that you are seeing I would suggest perhaps refactoring some code and or add some Logging everywhere along with the Method name that was called and or run.. and start removing error logging until you can pinpoint the exact method and or where in the process this is happening ..

Comment: hi DJ KRAZE thanks for the advice, but do you think that is it possible the client has successfully send data to server but the client still receives exception which cause it to resend again? That is the possible guess I have know. I would possible add some logging and monitor in production first.

Comment: try adding some Message checks / sent logic to the Client and see if you can some how code some synchronous / await type of coding where you can check if the message was received or processed on the server side.. you would need from my point of view some sort of `Ack - Nack` logic

Comment: I'd think using some kind of message-queueing middleware that's already solved these kind of problems would be far saner than trying to build it all again yourself, from scratch.